# Reverse custom layout for outgoing message

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I have a listview like picture on the right:

[image]

This listview is used for messaging. I was wondering how I could reverse the layout of the sender's message.

In more detail.
I need the messages from sender to:

IMAGEVIEW ALIGN TO THE RIGHT OF SCREEN.

TITLE TO ALIGN TO THE RIGHT BUT LEFT OF IMAGEVIEW.

MESSAGE TO ALIGN TO THE RIGHT BUT LEFT OF IMAGEVIEW AND BENEATH TITLE.

TIME ALIGN TO LEFT AND BOTTOM OF LAYOUT PER ITEM.(NOT SHOWN IN IMAGE)

Basically I need the existing layout to reverse for the sender messages.
I have code but currently not in front of my computer.
If code is needed I wil gladly add it.
I'm using a basic BaseAdapter to load listview.

ADDED

Here's the custom row layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/chatView">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/messenger_pic"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profile" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:id="@+id/messenger_name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="118dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/messenger_message"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/messenger_time"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my BaseAdapter Class:

```
class Messengeradapt extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<chat_messages> messageArray = M.messageArray;


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return messageArray.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return messageArray.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            chat_messages temp = messageArray.get(position);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_view, parent, false);
            TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.messenger_name);
            TextView message = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.messenger_message);
            TextView time = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.messenger_time);
            ImageView picture = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.messenger_pic);

            if ((e.FirstnName + " " + e.LastName).equals(temp.from_name)){

                String imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.52/android_connect/pictures/"+ e.FirstnName + " " + e.LastName + ".jpg";
                imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
                imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getActivity()));
                imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, picture);

                name.setText(e.FirstnName + " " + e.LastName);
                message.setText(temp.message);
                time.setText(temp.time);
            }
            else
            {
                String imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.52/android_connect/pictures/"+ C.contactname + ".jpg";
                imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
                imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getActivity()));
                imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, picture);

                name.setText(C.contactname);
                message.setText(temp.message);
                time.setText(temp.time);
            }

            return row;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add new chat_view_reverse.xml with following code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/chatView">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/messenger_time"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:id="@+id/messenger_name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="118dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/messenger_message"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/messenger_pic"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profile" />



    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

then edit your base adapter getView() with flag condition for normal or reverse view

```
if(reverse_flag){
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_view, parent, false);
}else{
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_view_reverse, parent, false);
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer with code, hope it will work..!!

Comment: Getting error at if(reverse_flag). Did I miss something?

Comment: I figured it out. I used your code and my if statement is based on the username that is signed in.

Comment: Ohh..great..Cheers..!!

Answer (score 1):

u have two ways
easy way is
in layout create two sepearte layouts one is for sender message, another is for rcever message,just hide and visible the layout which u want.
if it is sender msg hide receiver vice versa.

another way is set layout right side programatically.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)layout.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Im getting an error at layout.getLayoutParams();. Code added please take a look and thank you for your time.

Comment: here layout is your layout,which u want to align right side.replace layout with your layout name you declared.

Comment: Ok I see left parenthesis missing on cast. Checking it now.

Comment: Sorry but app crashes with error:  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
                                                                                     at com.hoodcoder.alltradessidekick.Ui.Messages.Messenger$Messengeradapt.getView(Messenger.java:234)

Comment: did u understand the first way, taking two views in single layout one is left side another is right side u can try that.

Comment: I see a Boolean is added. Great Ill try to implement in my code and let you know how it goes. I appreciate it.